# rails 3 activescaffold --ID-- strange behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activescaffold

Its a scream of my soul ))
I didn't never see such behavior before.
active_scaffold 3.0.3 rc

I am trying to add a custom action:

```
config.action_links.add 'zip_consumer_images', 
  :controller => '/services',
  :label => 'images', 
  :page => true, 
  :type => :member
```

Also my routes:

```
get 'services/zip_consumer_images' => 'services#zip_consumer_images'

namespace :admin do 
    resources :events do
      as_routes
      member do
        get 'images'
      end
    end
end
```

when I try /admin/events I get an error:

**No route matches {:action=>"zip_consumer_images", :id=>"--ID--", :controller=>"admin/services"}**

And another one strange behavior is that sometimes it works. I know it sounds strange but after 10-20 attempts **/admin/events** one time it works without any errors and I see my custom action labeled **images** with correct link  **services/zip_consumer_images?id=10**.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please don't use activescaffold. It's terrible and gets in your way more often than it helps. I would really recommend building this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **collection** instead of **member**:

```
namespace :admin do 
    resources :events do
      as_routes
      collection do
        get 'images'
      end
    end
end
```